# Line-spacing for lengthy question titles in timeline is far too much

Tags: feature-request, design, title, timeline

In the timeline of questions with lengthy titles such as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359440/timeline) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/332745/timeline) one, there is an insane amount of space between one line and the next in the title:

[image]

The `line-height` of `2.22` is simply too much.  Can we please change that `2.22` to something like `1.4`, or `1.35`, so it looks:

[image]

Like that?  On SO, some of the titles are long enough so that the lines are separated by an `<hr>` header.  Let's fix that, please.

Comment: Probably the [longest title's CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiVAP.png) is on this [question on Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/105389/timeline); which occupies **3** lines and clearly exacerbates the problem.

Comment: @Rob view that in a small screen, then it spans 7 lines.

Comment: @RandomPerson I have no idea if you also flagged this to request that a [tag:status-review] tag be added or not, but as I mentioned [over here](/questions/376439/change-to-https-links-in-the-userstab-moderators-page#comment1274078_376439) it's really likely that SE is going to do *nothing* on this without the [tag:status-review] tag being added first. Adding a bounty puts more *user* eyes on this, but it *doesn't* put SE's eyes on it. If the feature request/bug has a reasonable amount of support (score) and isn't controversial (usually demonstrated by a mix of up/down-votes), then

Comment: *by far* the most effective thing to do is to get the [tag:status-review] tag added to the the question by flagging it. If there's already support, then adding a bounty isn't an effective method of getting a [tag:feature-request] or [tag:bug] actually resolved. If there isn't a "reasonable" amount of support, then, yes, a bounty could be a good idea to get more user's eyes on it. What represents a "reasonable amount of support" really depends on what the request is, but this seems like a low effort bug/feature request which should be find to bring to SE's attention with the existing support.